Filter files from a folder
Lets say i have a 5 different folders and inside each folder i have 10 files. Now i have to extract only single files from each folder and those files need to use as a source (ADLS Gen2) for copy data activity and load into Target (SQL Table). This i need to acheive by using Filter activity condition. So how can i write that condition for multiple files inside multiple folders
I tried by writing expression inside Filter activity as @endswith(item().name,'_Filter.txt','_Condition.txt','_Env.txt','_escape.txt','_name.txt'). But it is throwing error as function endswith doesnot accept 5 arguments.

The correct expression for filtering multiple files from multiple folders using the endsWith function in the Filter activity is:
@or(or(or(or(endsWith(item().name, '_Filter.txt'),
    endsWith(item().name, '_Condition.txt')),endsWith(item().name, '_Env.txt')),endsWith(item().name, '_escape.txt')),endsWith(item().name, '_name.txt'))


The expression you gave had multiple arguments for endsWith() function. Above is the correct way of doing for your requirement.
